# Prevent grey overlay on touchstart in mobile Safari/Webview

Tags: ios, webkit, mobile-safari

I am building an iOS app in webkit, so my whole UI is a webview. on touchStart of any element near the outer boundary of the webview (that does not have a touchStart event bound to it), I get a translucent grey box overlay the full area of the webview. I've eliminated `-webkit-tap-highlight-color` or `-webkit-touch-callout` as causes. What do I do to remove this behavior?

Answer (score 76):

just put this style, you still have the default actions but without the gray overlay

```
a {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

if you want to remove the actions panel, just put this

```
a {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}
```

And there you go! clean links at last!

Comment: Works like a charm. I used 
*{ -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0); }
To remove it from everything

Comment: This is awesome, can you tell me how you found that out, I've been googling a list of webkit prefixes/pseudo-classes for safari mobile but find nothing.

Comment: @RoderickObrist You might find the [Apple Developers Mobile Safari](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html) reference useful.

Comment: Also I'd suggest that removing the highlight from all elements as @spadict mentioned is a bad idea for UX - the highlight is important in establishing the touch target of an element. If you see the first link you hit has a large touch target, it reduces effort in future interactions as per Fitt's Law. Seems to have a surprisingly large effect on usability.

Comment: Oy @SimonRobb, in defence of my comment, I'd say the context dictates whether or not removing it from everything is a good idea. People can make their own UX choices. Using the '*' universal selector as a whole  is a debate in and of itself.

Comment: Apologies @spadict - was intended not as a criticism but as a caution to anybody else who might come along. Their UX choices given that info are indeed their own :)

Answer (score 7):

My working solution is to capture and preventDefault on the `touchstart` event of the body of the html document. All other more explicit event handlers are unaffected. I did run into an issue with `select` elements, which I addressed in the body event handler (I'm using jQuery):

```
$('body').live(
'touchstart', 
function(e){
    if(e.target.localName != 'select'){
        e.preventDefault(); 
    }
}
```

)

Comment: The css soluton seems a little fine though

Comment: This solution is much better even if it isn't "native" although it should use .on I think instead of .live