# How to remove bar chart's grayish flash effect in highcharts

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, highcharts

I made bar charts using Highcharts library.
[image]

But when I click the graph anywhere, a gray flash effect appears and goes away within a fraction. I want to remove that flash effect.

**PS** : I don't want to disable interaction for entire graph. 
Please guide me for the same.

Comment: I've tested this example http://jsfiddle.net/yE2c2/ and problem doesn't appear, could you update my code with yours? Problem is only in mobile devices?

Comment: The problem is only with mobile devices and mobile browsers.

Comment: I advice to familiar with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106934/prevent-grey-overlay-on-touchstart-in-mobile-safari-webview

Comment: Thanks that's preventing the flash :)