# How to disable touch overlay in windows8 mobile application

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, windows-phone-8

[image]

I need to avoid this squire shaped overlay.
I am using html5 for the development. please help me :)

Comment: `outline: none;` maybe?

Comment: Thanks  Derek 朕會功夫 , I already tried that, but its not working

Comment: I don't have a windows mobile so I can't test it but the same situation happens in android and iOS. Maybe this will work for you if you change the prefixes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106934/prevent-grey-overlay-on-touchstart-in-mobile-safari-webview

Comment: Thanks  Derek 朕會功夫 , i used that css style in my button , its not working , the dark overlay comes when i am using on click function .

Comment: Thanks Zubair Lawrence this code is working, now my design problems are cleared , Thanks a lot ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for:

```
<meta name="misapplication-tap-highlight" content="no"/>
```